# Как использовать условный оператор, если позиция отсутствует?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

[image: ошибка]

[image: ошибки]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
from csv import writer
from lxml import html

headers = {
    'accept': 'image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/94.0.0.0 (Edition Yx 02)'

}

import xlsxwriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'accept': 'image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 '
                  'Safari/537.36 OPR/94.0.0.0 (Edition Yx 02)'

}

url = 'https://www.divan.ru/category/krovati/'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')  # создаем суп

pagination = soup.find('div', class_='dqBvL').find_all('a')
pages = int(pagination[-2].text)

print(f'Всего страниц: {pages}')

# Номер текущего товара
block_no = 1

data = []

for page in range(1, pages + 1):
    page_response = requests.get(url + f'page-{page}', headers=headers)
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text, 'lxml')
    # Находим все блоки с товаром
    blocks = page_soup.find('div', class_='Lei8X').find_all('div', class_='LlPhw')
    price = page_soup.find('div', class_='Lei8X').find_all('div', class_='LlPhw')

    # Проходимся по ним
    for block in blocks:

        # Ищем наименование
        title = block.find('a', {'class': 'ImmXq dpmhZ b8BqN ProductName'}).text.strip()
        price = block.find('span', {'class': 'Zq2dF F9ye5 KIkOH'}).text.strip()
       
        data.append([block_no, title, price])
        block_no += 1
        print(title, price)
```

Я собираю информацию с сайта "Наименование" и "Цена". На последних страницах товар присутствует, но нет цены, написано "товар отсутствует". Там где товар отсутствует нет тега span, но появляется тег div class_= gWTeQ zR619, где "товар отсутствует". Как сделать, чтобы при парсинге, если цена отсутствует, он передавал тег - "товар отсутствует".

Comment: уберите из кода все ненужное и оставьте только то, что относится к проблеме.

Comment: откройте нужную страницу и посмотрите внимательно, что происходит после загрузки. Станет понятно, откуда берется цена.

Comment: @Эникейщик, зачем убирать все не нужное ? Если для анализа нужен весь товар даже с учетом его отсутствия.

Comment: @Эникейщик, так не прокатит, как вы пишите: "откройте нужную страницу и посмотрите внимательно, что происходит после загрузки. Станет понятно, откуда берется цена". Здесь надо методом исключения. А именно условные операторы применять if и else.

Comment: У вас в коде не то что вы видите в браузере. Код HTML страницы разный, в коде вы скачиваете исходный HTML-код, в брайзере вы видете исходный HTML-код над которым поколдовал JavaScript. Если вам нужен HTML-код как в браузере то воспользуйтесь например, селенимумом. Эникейщик имел виду глянуть сам исходный код страницы в котором как раз и прописаны ценники вместо "товар отсутствует". При желанний это можно наглядно увидеть в самом браузере.

Comment: А речь не об анализе, а о вопросе. В коде много лишнего, не относящегося напрямую к проблеме. Например, все, что относится к экселю из вопроса нужно убрать.

Comment: @Эникейщик, что значит убрать, если это надо записать в файл ? Если не соображаете, зачем пишите ? Если знаете делайте правку в коде.

Comment: неудивительно, что ты по каждой мелочи приходишь сюда. Удивительно, что ты не понимаешь простых вещей сказаных понятным русским языком. В вопросе должен быть только тот код, который относится к твоей проблеме. Запись в файл к твоей проблеме не относится. [ask]

Comment: @Эникейщик, не согласен. Кто-то может быть знает, как изменения внести в файл, а не в консоль ?

Comment: какие изменения? Вопрос в том, что парсер берет не то, что требуется. А что там потом с этими данными происходит вообще не имеет никакого значения. Хоть в эксель, хоть в телеграм, хоть в корзину, на парсинг сайта это никак не влияет.

Comment: @Эникейщик, мелочь ни мелочь, а из 20 и более просмотров. Только один может дать развернутый ответ. Вот такие программисты....Видимо Ваш уровень. Внесите изменения в код, а зачем воздух сотрясать ?

Comment: Смотри: если я скопирую этот код себе и попытаюсь его запустить, то он не запустится, потому что у меня нет половины модулей, который там импортируются. Самое веселое (о чем я уже сказал, но ты не в состоянии осмыслить) - эти модули для воспроизведения проблемы совсем не нужны. Чистить код, чтобы его запустить и помочь кому-то там из интернета, я не собираюсь. Помощь нужна тебе, и это ты должен делать так, чтобы другим было удобно тебе помогать.

Comment: `div class_=['class1', 'class2']` в данном случае будет работать логика "ИЛИ"

Comment: @Namerek, это как ? Дело в том, что за цену отвечат тег span. А там где цена отсутствует, отвечает тег div. Которые оба встроенны в ОБЩИЙ тег div. Но дело в том, что программа НИКАК не хочет видеть тег div - "Товар отсутствует". Следовательно, надо исходить из того, что если программа НЕ ВИДИТ ТЕГ SPAN. В print добавить "Товар отсутствует". Но и тут  у меня загвозка. При условном операторе if и else. ОН ВИДИТ ТОЛЬКО ELSE . И выдает по всем позициям без разбору "Товар отсутствует". Вот проблема в чем.

Comment: Ну сейчас у вас похоже `Selenium` не может `chromedriver` найти. Почитайте больше про настройку `Selenium`.

Answer (score 2):

Открыв сайт на последней странице, мы увидим что плашки "Товар отсутствует" появляются уже после загрузки страницы значит `requests` не поможет. Нужно использовать `selenium` Вот исправленный код переписанный на `selenium` (Нужно установить `selenium`  командой `pip install selenium` и `webdriver_manager` командой `pip install webdriver_manager`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

url = 'https://www.divan.ru/category/krovati/'

# Создаем новый браузер
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)

browser.get(url)  # Открываем страницу

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')  # создаем суп

pagination = soup.find('div', class_='dqBvL').find_all('a')
pages = int(pagination[-2].text)

print(f'Всего страниц: {pages}')

# Номер текущего товара
block_no = 1

data = []

for page in range(1, pages + 1):
    browser.get(url + f'page-{page}')
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    # Находим все блоки с товаром
    blocks = page_soup.find('div', class_='Lei8X').find_all('div', class_='LlPhw')
    price = page_soup.find('div', class_='Lei8X').find_all('div', class_='LlPhw')

    # Проходимся по ним
    for block in blocks:
        # Ищем наименование
        title = block.find('a', {'class': 'ImmXq dpmhZ b8BqN ProductName'}).text.strip()
        if block.find('div', {'class': 'gWTeQ zR619'}) is not None:
            price = 'Товар отсутствует'  # Если есть плашка нет в наличии
        else:
            price = block.find('span', {'class': 'Zq2dF F9ye5 KIkOH'}).text.strip()

        data.append([block_no, title, price])
        block_no += 1
        print(title, price)

browser.quit()  # Закрываем браузер

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('m.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    content = ["N", "Наименование", "Цена"]

    worksheet.write_row(0, 0, content)

    for index, row in enumerate(data, start=1):
        worksheet.write_row(index, 0, row)

    worksheet.autofit()  # Подбираем размер ячеек (Необязательно, но приятно)
```

Comment: спасибо, но появилось кучу ошибок. Прикрепил выше.

Comment: @МаксимДовгань исправил для автоматической установки webdriver-а Chrome

Comment: [WDM] - Downloading: 100%|##########| 6.81M/6.81M [00:00<00:00, 11.9MB/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Максим\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ И ниже ругается на webdriver.py

Comment: @МаксимДовгань у вас установлен Chrome на компьютере?

Comment: я сейчас обратил внимание, что на ярлыке ChroN Browser. ChroN и ChroM одно и тоже ?

Comment: ярлык говорит, что это chrom.exe но папка chroN называется. Может папку переименовать ? Чтобы программа видела ?

Comment: @МаксимДовгань достаточно после строки `options.add_argument("--headless")` добавить `options.binary_location = "Путь к chrome.exe"`

Comment: ругается на browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service). Ниже: 'Сообщение: сеанс не создан: Эта версия ChromeDriver поддерживает только Chrome версии 113
Текущая версия браузера - 102.0.5005.167"

Comment: @МаксимДовгань откройте Chrome он должен предлагать обновление

Comment: обнавлял до предыдущего коммента. Может проблема в ChromeDriver ???

Comment: Откройте Chrome три точки -> Настройки -> О браузере Chrome и напишите версию которая там указана, чтобы понять в чём именно проблема. Если 102, то замените `service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())` на `service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager(version='102.0.5005.61').install())`

Comment: получилось. ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ СПАСИБО !!! ;))))

Answer (score 0):

```
tag = soup.find('div', {'class': 'my-class'})

if tag is not None:
    # выполнение кода, если тег найден
else:
    # выполнение кода, если тег не найден
```

Comment: не подскажите, куда вставить ? Так как я сделал, он заменяет все цены на "товар отсутствует", то есть без реальной картины.